# missing info when submit app

Tags: iphone, ios

I am about to submit my iPhone app to apple store, a quick question:

If half way, I found that I missed something/information, say a screenshot, and it takes me 2 days to get that screenshot, does apple store remember all the steps that I already completed - so that I can restart from where I was, or do I need to restart from the beginning?

Comment: You can edit most details at any time. Such as the description and screenshots. So you won't have to fill out the description again if you just want to add/change a screenshot or two. You can NOT change the app catagory once it's been approved at least until the next update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a screenshot that's missing, go ahead and submit it, and update the screenshot later. That won't cause your app to get re-reviewed, and it usually takes Apple a few days to start reviewing your app anyhow.

To answer your question directly, I don't recall that Apple saves the info that you've already entered if you don't go ahead and submit the changes. I think you either have to submit it or retype it later if you don't submit it now.